# What are the preferred subsystems of the universe?

Tags: particle-physics, emergent-properties

I am not a physicist but I am interested in philosophical implications of theoretical physics. My understanding is that many physical properties like mass, volume, temperature etc. - are emergent properties resulting from interacting elementary particles. On the other hand, properties like charge, spin, color etc applied to "individual" elementary particles. So my question is: can we speak of fundamental properties of matter that are not emergent and what are the entities that carry those properties?

Comment: Theoretical physics doesn't have any philosophical implications. It's simply a set of mathematical tools to describe nature. What an emergent property is is simply a choice of the level of theory we are using. One theory's results are another theory's assumptions. All theories are, by the way, wrong. They are "right enough" within their limited domain of application and that is what makes them useful.

Comment: There are people who would deny that "particles" are the fundamental objects, and go to fields instead. Others insist the particles are fundamental and construct the fields from them. This alone shows this is *primarily opinion-based*.

Comment: May be this is the wrong forum for questions like that. But as  a non-professional I assume that there is some metaphysical framework in theoretical physics that allows description of natural phenomena in philosophical terms like objects and properties. Do levels of theory correspond to levels of nature, or merely the human way of thinking?

Comment: After some digging around I found the metaphysical framework known in theoretical physics as [preferred basis](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/66258). It turns out that lowest level objects and properties in quantum physics are called "preferred subsystems" of the Universe. What they are - seems to be an open problem also know as "set selection" which is  analogous to the question of whether an abstract formulation of classical mechanics is satisfactory in the absence of a clear link between the mathematical formalism and our experiences